# SSH и удаленное взаимодействие с экраном при помощи pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, pyautogui, openssh, виртуальная-машина

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть виртуальная машина c Windows 10, есть скрипт который при помощи:

```
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    pyautogui.click(...)
    pyautogui.keyUp(...)
    pyautogui.keyDown(...)
```

Шарит по окну приложения и делает рутинную работу. При нажатии на определенную кнопку с основной системы, заданную в скрипте, код приостанавливает свою работу, не полностью перестает работать, а приостанавливает свою работу.
Можно ли как-то подключаться при помощи ssh к виртуальной машине, запускать скрипт и при этом чтобы все клики скрипта отражались на виртуальной машине, а при попытке приостановить скрипт, это можно было бы сделать с основной системы, которая так же под управлением Windows 10 (в командной строке с которой производилась попытка подключение по SSH)?